# CSS not applying on WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, html, css, android-activity, webview

I have my **style.css** file in **src/main/assets** folder.

I am using followig code to add style.css in html

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(Tab1.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\"  
rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body>");
    sb.append(message);
    sb.append("</body></HTML>");
```

**Message contain the content inside of body tag of what i get from XML parsing of description tag**
Now i load it with the following code but it didn't work. It does not apply style.css file on it

```
WebView myColoumnView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ColoumnView);
myColoumnView.loadDataWithBaseURL("\"file:///android_asset/\"style.css",sb.toString(), mimeType, encoding, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a path issue. In `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, the path data seems wrong to me. It should be like this:

```
 myColoumnView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",  // avoid anti slash "\"
          sb.toString(), // no need to add CSS file above, it should be append to this line
          mimeType, 
          encoding, 
          null);
```

It should work correctly.